# On which day in Teveis did this happen?

Tags: calendar, megillat-esther

In [Megilas Esther 2:16](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%90%D7%A1%D7%AA%D7%A8_%D7%91_%D7%98%D7%96) it mentions that Esther was taken in Teveis to Achasverosh's palace. Does anyone know on which day of the month this happened?

Comment: The Me'am Loez doesn't say.

Answer (score 4):

According to an online sources, it was on 1 Tevet.

http://www.chabad.org/calendar/view/day.asp?tDate=12/8/2010

I'd have to look in the Mefarshim to see if they say which date it was on.

Comment: Jeff Alhadeff, Welcome to mi.yodeya, and thanks very much for this bit of research! We'd love to have you as a fully-registered member, which you can accomplish by clicking "register," above.

Comment: There is no source for 1 Teveis on the Chabad website?

Comment: I don't know an ultimate source for this, but Devar Yom Beyomo (by R' Chaim Knoller) also says that it was on 1 Teves (http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=31168&pgnum=389). Could be that it's in the spirit of לא בא הכתוב לסתום אלא לפרש: if it gives a month, we should assume that it's the first day of that month unless otherwise indicated.

Answer (score 1):

The רמ"א reportedly says it was the 9th of טבת.

It is *not* the רמ"א on [או"ח סימן תקפ](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%AA%D7%A7%D7%A4), although it is ostensibly the event commemorated by the fast on the ninth of טבת. I have heard this by rumor only so far and will try to find a link inside.

Comment: Perhaps it's in his commentary on Esther (Mechir Yayin IINM)

Comment: Yup. Here it is http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40161&st=&pgnum=44