# Why is Aharon the only person in Tanac"h who's death date is specifically mentioned?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, yahrtzeit, masei, aharon

AFAIK, Aharon is the only person in Tana"ch whose death date I specifically mentioned. See [Bamidbar 33:38](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0433.htm#38), I know that Aharon was a *Chashuver Yid*, but was makes him so special that only he of all important people in Tana"ch has his yahrtzeit mentioned?

Comment: Miriam's may be mentioned. Also Gedalia ben Achikam. We know the death date of 10 of Haman's sons. Probably some others, I'm guessing. Why do you think he's the only one?

Comment: possible dupe? http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/17810/759

Comment: @DoubleAA - Miriam's exact Yahrtzeit date is not specifically mentioned. It is derived from mentioning her death with the date that B'nai Yisra'el arrived at Kadesh, I believe. I may have the location wrong. Have to look up Gedaliah's death date.