# Timeline of the events in the midbar

Tags: product-recommendation, time, dor-hamidbar, bamidbar-numbers-book-of

I'm looking for a timeline that explains when the events in the midbar (or sefer Bamidbar) happened or at least in what order they happened in. E.g. The story of Miriam, the spies, Korach, the giving of the mitzvah of parah adumah, etc.

Comment: Related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/17810/759

Comment: I think the targum yonasan on masai says what happened at each stop.

Answer (score 3):

The Sefer קורות הדורות [זילבר] חלק ב' דף ל"ז has a nice timeline in Hebrew. For all the footnotes and more details, you would want to see the sefer itself.

[image][image][image][image][image]

[image]

Comment: Do you have a link to either this Sefer or a website where it can be purchased?